# Applications of group theory in astronomy

Tags: astronomy, group-theory, group-representations, solar-system, algebraic-geometry

I am familiar with applications of representation/group theory in terms of symmetries in quantum mechanics and general relativity, but what are some of their applications in astronomy? More specifically (if attainable), I am interested in finding a way group theory could explain solar-system formations or planet searches. Any link between g.t. and astronomy is appreciated.

Comment: This question (v2) seems like a list question.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/474884/